# Coding a robot in Webots

Tags: webots

As a beginner, I just installed Webots and imported 2 industrial robots (Kuka Youbot and the ABB IRB4600).

My questions:
Looking into each robot in the scene tree: I couldn't see any child parts under the parent. Are those parts hidden for some reason?
Coding in C or in Python:
 By means of what instruction can I move such a robot to a certain XYZ position?
And by means of what instruction can I move each separate axis of the robot?

I couldn't find any specific documentation on that; any link will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**I couldn't see any child parts under the parent**.

***RE -*** Right-click on the parent and click on convert to base nodes

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPGQ5.png)

Comment: Thanks, Binula. It works that way when I build a machine myself, but when importing an external robot, it just won't open beyond the root node. Not seeing the sub-nodes makes it impossible to address the robot's parts by code unless the creator would provide a manual with a clear description.